# Working Leads/Prospects

Tags: attracting-clients

I am doing some cold calling and I had some interest with a few prospects. I sent them some of my previous work and have yet to hear back from them. Mind you, it's only been a couple days. I want to call them and thought about our previous conversation.

I don't want to come off as desperate but I do want to keep the interest/excitement up. Am I over-thinking calling too soon or is it smarter to give them a few days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you called THEM so probably your services are not very urgent to them at this moment. Looking up your samples and making the decision takes up time from their already pretty much full schedule. They are (typically) nice people and (some of them) want to work with you, so do not expect anything wrong if they have not rushed to assess your offer. Again, you are probably not at the top of their TODO list, not yet.

Your task is to keep yourself in this list without bugging them too much. I personally consider it polite to follow-up once in a business week. Try not to sound as if they owe you something.

Comment: Thanks Anton, you are right. I did a follow up and at the end for the work week and they still needed some time. In the beginning of the conversation, they owner said they were swamped.